# Sorting based on a variable number of sort keys input after execution

Tags: python

I am very new to python and my apologies is this has already been answered.  I can see a lot of previous answers to 'sort' questions but my problem seems a little different from these questions and answers.

I have a list of keys, with each key contained in a tuple, that I am trying to sort.  Each key is derived from a subset of the columns in a CSV file, but this subset is determined by the user at runtime and can't be hard coded as it will vary from execution to execution.  I also have a datetime value that will always form part of the key as the last item in the tuple (so there will be at least one item to sort on - even if the user provides no additional items).

The tuples to be sorted look like:

```
(col0, col1, .... colN, datetime)
```

Where col0 to colN are based on the values found in columns in a CSV file, and the 'N' can change from run to run.

In each execution, the tuples in the list will always have the same number of items in each tuple.  However, they need to be able to vary from run to run based on user input.

The sort looks like:

```
sorted(concurrencydict.keys(), key=itemgetter(0, 1, 2))
```

... when I do hard-code the sort based on the first three columns.  The issue is that I don't know in advance of execution that 3 items will need to be sorted - it may be 1, 2, 3 or more.

I hope this description makes sense.

I haven't been able to think of how I can get itemgetter to accept a variable number of values.

Does anyone know whether there is an elegant way of performing a sort based on a variable number of items in python where the number of sort items is determined at run time (and not based on fixed column numbers or attribute names)?

Comment: `key=itemgetter(*sort_columns)`?

Comment: Too easy - my newness to python I'm afraid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll turn my comment into an answer.

You can pass a variable number of arguments (which are packed into an iterable object) by using `*args` in the function call. In your specific case, you can put your user-supplied selection of column numbers to sort by into a `sort_columns` list or tuple, then call:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(concurrencydict.keys(), key=itemgetter(*sort_columns))
```